# Conversion from cartesian to spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

Let $$P:[0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi)\;,\;\;\;(r,\theta,\phi)\mapsto r\begin{pmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$ denote the transformation from spherical to cartesian coordinates. If $(r,\theta,\phi)\in[0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi)$ and $p:=(x,y,z):=P(r,\theta,\phi)$, we know that

1. $|p|=r$
2. If $r>0$, then $$\cos\theta=\frac zr$$ and hence $$\theta=\arccos\frac zr$$
3. If $r>0$ and $\sin\theta>0$ (i.e. $\theta\in(0,\pi)$), then \begin{align}\cos\phi&=\frac x{r\sin\theta}\\\sin\phi&=\frac y{r\sin\theta}\end{align}

   - If further $x>0$, then $$\phi=\begin{cases}\arctan\frac yx&\text{, if }y\ge0\\2\pi+\arctan\frac yx&\text{, if }y\le 0\end{cases}$$
   - If $x<0$ instead, then $$\phi=\pi+\arctan\frac yx$$
   - Lastly, if $x=0$, then $$\phi=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac\pi2&\text{, if }y>0\\\displaystyle\frac{3\pi}2&\text{, if }y<0\end{cases}$$ ($y=0$ is impossible in this case)

> So, altogether, $P$ is injective on $(0,\infty)\times(0,\pi)\times[0,2\pi)$. Now consider the conversion from cartesian to spherical coordinates described [here](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Color_and_Radiometry/Working_with_Radiometric_Integrals.html#IntegralsoverSphericalCoordinates) (after the line "*The conversion of a direction to spherical angles can be found by ...*"). They use the [$\operatorname{atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function to obtain $\phi$ via $\phi=\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$. Why is this correct even when $\sin\theta=0$? Am I missing something or are they wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This may be implementation-dependent, but in at least some implementations of the standard C++ math library,
`double t = std::atan2(0,0)` simply sets `t` to zero.
That seems to be as good a result as any when you are setting the angle $\phi$ for Cartesian coordinates of the form $(0,0,z).$

It is possible that the authors of [the page you were concerned about](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Color_and_Radiometry/Working_with_Radiometric_Integrals.html#IntegralsoverSphericalCoordinates)
used an implementation of `std::atan2` that does not produce a domain error when $x=y=0,$ and that they assumed the reader would use such an implementation too.

But it is also possible that the application described on that page
never sets $x = y = 0$ simultaneously.
After all, the formula $\mathrm d\omega = \sin\theta\, \mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi$
gives a useful result only when $\sin\theta\neq 0.$

It is also possible that the authors eventually use their `SphericalPhi` function on an implementation in which `atan2(0,0)` produces a domain error, in an application that can call this function when $x=y=0,$ in a place where `NaN` is not an acceptable value for `SphericalPhi` to return (or the domain error raises an uncaught exception).
If all those things are true then you have found a defect in their software.

Of course we could avoid all these questions by adding an `if` within the function definition so that the function returns $0$ when $x=y=0$ regardless of the implementation of `atan2` (that is, it never calls `atan2` in that case).
The software engineer in me says, "Do this."
But someone who just wants the function for some scientific research of their own may have a different attitude toward portability and reliability.

Comment: Due to the standard, a "domain error may occur if `x` and `y` are both zero" and "if a domain error occurs, an implementation-defined value is returned (NaN where supported)". (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2.)

Comment: In the application in the link the conversion is used in other contexts than integration as well.

Comment: There is a world of difference between "**may** occur" and "**will** occur". Read the next two lines on the page where you got that quote: they explain one set of circumstances in which the domain error **does not** occur.

Comment: If there are other contexts where the function is used, it would be useful to cite them as well. Perhaps none of them encounter the case $\sin\theta=0,$ but it's hard to know whether they do or don't without knowing something about what they are.

Comment: I didn't wrote that it *will* occur, did I? Since you wrote "this *may* be implementation-dependent", it seemed to me that you're unsure about this and just wanted to clarify.

Comment: You can find the context I'm mostly interested in [here](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Light_Transport_I_Surface_Reflection/Sampling_Light_Sources.html#InfiniteAreaLights) at the very bottom of the page. It's perfectly possible that $\sin\theta=0$ there. Moreover, if they really assume that $\sin\theta\ne0$, I would expect that they mention this somewhere. But, sure, there's no guarantee.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I have certainly encountered implementations where the domain error does not occur. I think implementations exist where this does produce an error, but I am not certain about that. That is why I wrote "may."

Comment: Sure, all the standard says is that a domain error *may* occur, but it doesn't need to be. That's all I wrote. (In fact, if the implementation supports IEEE floating-point arithmetic (IEC 60559) it is even guaranteed a domain error will *not* occur.)

Comment: The second page you linked has a great many calculations, but the gist of it seems to be to sample a function somewhere inside a 2D region. If the 2D region comes from a mesh of spherical coordinates where $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ are mesh points, you certainly **will not** sample the function at a point where $\sin\theta=0.$